# Java's isInstance on Object?

Tags: java

I have an `Object` named `handler` and an instance of `Class` named `protocolInterface`. I want to know if `handler` implements `protocolInterface`. So far as I can tell, this isn't possible without resorting to reflection.

```
if (handler instanceof protoInterface.getClass())
```

results in a flurry of parsing errors, `')' expected` `illegal start of expression`, etc etc. So I thought I'd try the `isInstance()` method, but since `handler` is of type `Object`, it call's `Object`'s `IsInstance()`, which has no knowledge outside of itself. So even when `handler` implements `protocolInteface`, it returns false.

How can I reconcile this? The two ways of handling this seem mutually exclusive.

Comment: Use `instanceof` operator.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Even with instanceof, it gives the same error. First saying that protoInterface isn't a known class. Then the parsing error when adding getClass().

Comment: You should just type the name of your class, don't use `className.getClass()`.

Comment: if (handler instanceof protoInterface)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the class that will be passed. This is an a method that takes a Class as a parameter.

Comment: Not the class that will be passed, but your interface. You can search for a tutorial about using `instanceof` and create a simple test in a console app. This is no rocket science, tho.

Comment: If you have a parse error, we may need to see more of the code, especially the signature of the method this snippet comes from.

Comment: The Class object for the interface *is* the class being passed. There is a Class object being passed in, and I want to test if 'handler' is an instance of it. A simple instanceof doesn't work when the class you're testing against is an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `isInstance()` method on `Class` that will tell you if a given object is an instance of the target type, e.g.:

```
if (protoInterface.getClass().isInstance(handler)) { ... }
```

Comment: Ahh, you are quite right, I had the relationships backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class handlerClass = handler.getClass();
Class protocolClass = protocolInterface.getClass();
if (protocolClass.isAssignableFrom(handlerClass)) {
    ... // yadda yadda yadda
}
```

Obviously you can make this a one-liner; I thought this made it a bit clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(protoInterface.getClass().isAssignableFrom(handler.getClass())
```